# Permanently redirect www and apex domain to subdomain on netlify

Tags: netlify

on namecheap I own a site called anonplayer.com and I have used custom dns to point it to netlify servers

on netlify i'm running an app at test.anonplayer.com which works fine but I have been unable to get anonplayer.com and www.anonplayer.com to permanently redirect to test.anonplayer.com

I tried both CNAME and ALIAS records from their domains section

and I also tried the following _redirects in the public folder of my vue app

```
/*    /index.html   200
https://anonplayer.com https://test.anonplayer.com
https://www.anonplayer.com https://test.anonplayer.com
https://anonplayer.com/* https://test.anonplayer.com/:splat
https://www.anonplayer.com/* https://test.anonplayer.com/:splat
```

and I get "5 redirect rules processed, All redirect rules deployed without errors" in the build logs.

does it have something to do with the fact that I have another site app.anonplayer.com running on netlify ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be the same as setting up a site with a `www` sub-domain on Netlify. Netlify will automatically enter these settings for you into DNS.

- Create a site for your bare domain `aanonplayer.com`
- Add domain aliases `test.aanonplayer.com` and `www.aanonplayer.com`
- Make `test.aanonplayer.com` the primary

In `_redirects` for your site, use the following:

```bash
# Redirect domain aliases to primary domain
https://aanonplayer.com/* https://test.aanonplayer.com/:splat 301!
https://www.aanonplayer.com/* https://test.aanonplayer.com/:splat 301!

# Optional: Redirect default Netlify subdomain to primary domain
https://aanonplayer-com.netlify.com/* https://test.aanonplayer.com/:splat 301!
```

In Domain settings for the site, you should see something similar to:

[image]

In DNS you would see something similar to:

[image]

Comment: The permanent redirects work correctly when I followed you advice but I ran into new problems and have edited my question to reflect that. Should I accept this answer and ask a new question instead ?

Comment: Yeah, the issue may be spa related and have nothing to do with the redirects.

Comment: you're right my router was at fault, just had to fix that and add "/* /index.html 200" below the suggested rules, then everything was perfect. Thanks for the help

Comment: anyone who follows this should use @talves ' answer specifically the `!` at the end of the redirect rules, and also what the OP discovered around the ORDERING of the redirects - general catch-all /* must come after the hostname-specific redirects.